# DataTables warning: table id=table4 - Invalid JSON response

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, datatables, codeigniter-3

I'm maintaining a simple web app created using codeigniter 3.5, it is already on production for quite some time. It works just fine until earlier this morning it prompt an error:

> DataTables warning: table id=table4 - Invalid JSON response. For more
>   information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

I follow the link and the instructions there but it's still no good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must be because of incorrect API response. Following is the sample code to return the json data for datatable:

```
var data = <GetDataFromDB>
return Json(new { Result = "<OK/ERROR>", Records = data});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you input data is invalid or invalid format.

You might be sending empty or spacial characters.

Please share some input data, so it will be easy to solve your problem.

You follow this link and verify input data.
[DataTable with Zero configuration](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html)